# How to listen to different listener with event delegation

Tags: javascript

I have some data created dynamically like the below snippet

```js
const resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
const getList = document.getElementById("example");

document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type && tgt.type === "radio") {
    const hide = tgt.classList.contains("verify-no");
    [...tgt.closest(".card-body").querySelectorAll("p.card-text")].forEach(par => par.classList.toggle("d-none", hide))
  }
})

getList.addEventListener("click", e => {

  let results = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  results.forEach((el, idx) => {
    //carousel
    const carouselItem = document.createElement("div");
    if (idx === 1) {
      carouselItem.classList.add("carousel-item", "active");
    }
    carouselItem.classList.add("carousel-item");

    //row below carousel
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add("row");

    //column for rows
    const column = document.createElement("div");
    column.classList.add("col-md-12", "mb-3");

    // card for each carousel inside column
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");

    // card body for card
    const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
    cardBody.classList.add("card-body", "text-center");

    // card text (upload info)
    const cardTextUploadedOn = document.createElement("p");
    cardTextUploadedOn.classList.add("card-text");
    cardTextUploadedOn.innerText = "adsadad";

    const cardTextUploadedBy = document.createElement("p");
    cardTextUploadedBy.classList.add("card-text");
    cardTextUploadedBy.innerText = "adsadad";

    // show predictions
    const formGroup = document.createElement("div");
    formGroup.classList.add("form-group", "row");

    const predLabel = document.createElement("div");
    predLabel.classList.add("col-lg-12");
    predLabel.innerText = "Select";

    const dummy = document.createElement("div");
    dummy.classList.add("col-sm-10");

    formGroup.appendChild(predLabel);
    formGroup.appendChild(dummy);

    // yes / no options
    const verifyRow = document.createElement("div");
    verifyRow.classList.add("row");

    const verifyLegend = document.createElement("legend");
    verifyLegend.classList.add("col-form-label", "col-lg-12", "pt-0");
    verifyLegend.innerText = "Is this correct ?";

    const verifyDummy = document.createElement("div");
    verifyDummy.classList.add("col-sm-10");

    const verifyYesFormCheck = document.createElement("div");
    verifyYesFormCheck.classList.add("form-check");

    const verifyNoFormCheck = document.createElement("div");
    verifyNoFormCheck.classList.add("form-check");

    const yesInput = document.createElement("input");
    yesInput.classList.add("form-check-input", "verify-yes");
    yesInput.type = "radio";
    yesInput.checked = true; // this will check it
    yesInput.name = "choosePred" + idx;
    yesInput.value = "Yes";

    const verifyYesLabel = document.createElement("label");
    verifyYesLabel.classList.add("form-check-label", "verify-yes");
    verifyYesLabel.innerText = "Yes";

    const verifyNoLabel = document.createElement("label");
    verifyNoLabel.classList.add("form-check-label", "verify-no");
    verifyNoLabel.innerText = "No";

    const noInput = document.createElement("input");
    noInput.classList.add("form-check-input", "verify-no");
    noInput.type = "radio";
    noInput.name = "choosePred" + idx;
    noInput.value = "No";

    // yes no options end

    // select //
    const selectForm = document.createElement("div");
    selectForm.classList.add("form-group", "selectGroup");

    const selectCLabel = document.createElement("label");
    selectCLabel.innerText = "Select C";

    const selectPLabel = document.createElement("label");
    selectPLabel.innerText = "Select P";

    //select for crop options
    const selectC = document.createElement("select");
    selectC.classList.add("form-control", "c-select");

    //select for pest options
    const selectP = document.createElement("select");
    selectP.classList.add("form-control", "p-select");

    const c_names = ['abc', 'abcd', 'gef']

    for (const c of c_names) {
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.innerText = c;
      if (c === "Select") {
        option.selected = true;
      }
      selectC.appendChild(option);
    }

    // select //
    resultsDiv.appendChild(carouselItem);
    carouselItem.appendChild(row);
    row.appendChild(column);
    column.appendChild(card);
    card.appendChild(cardBody);
    cardBody.appendChild(cardTextUploadedBy);
    cardBody.appendChild(cardTextUploadedOn);
    cardBody.appendChild(formGroup);
    cardBody.appendChild(verifyRow);
    verifyRow.appendChild(verifyLegend);
    verifyRow.appendChild(verifyDummy);
    verifyDummy.appendChild(verifyYesFormCheck);
    verifyDummy.appendChild(verifyNoFormCheck);
    verifyYesFormCheck.appendChild(yesInput);
    verifyYesFormCheck.appendChild(verifyYesLabel);
    verifyNoFormCheck.appendChild(noInput);
    verifyNoFormCheck.appendChild(verifyNoLabel);
    cardBody.appendChild(selectForm);
    selectForm.appendChild(selectCLabel);
    selectForm.appendChild(selectC);
    selectForm.appendChild(selectPLabel);
    selectForm.appendChild(selectP);

  });
  // if needed later
  // [...document.querySelectorAll(".verify-yes")].forEach(radio =>  radio.checked=true)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.4/cropper.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/advisory-new.css') }}" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="example">Show results</button>

  <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row m-auto">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h3 class="mb-3">Some heading</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
          <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11.793l-3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L13.293 8.5H1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8z" />
            </svg>
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15 8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H2.707l3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L2.707 8.5H14.5A.5.5 0 0 0 15 8z" />
            </svg>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 m-auto shadow-lg p-3">
          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" id="results"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here i have been already using an click listener to listen to dynamically created `radio` button ,
but I am stuck completely on how to listen to dynamically created `Select` -> on change listener

- please click on `show results` button to view carousel-items

Any help is much appreciated ...

Comment: You seem to include jquery. A jquery solution is `$('body').on('change','.p-select',function(){//your function});`

Comment: hey @biberman would this be similar to `body.addEventListener('change','.c-select',()=>{'do our thing'})` in vanilla js ? and is that it only listens when there is a change in `c-select` class ??

Comment: I don't see anything in your code where you tried to implement the event delegation for `change`?

Comment: @t.niese no mate , i haven't yett :( not because i don't know about adding lsiteners but because where and how can i add atleast to get a start

Comment: But you already have `document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", function(e) { … })` for the `click` event, so why don't you do the same for the `change` event? What is your problem with doing that?

Comment: I think you meant @ChrisLear - but the arrow function seems to be ok...

Comment: @Codenewbie yes. `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )` is the description of the jquery function. See https://api.jquery.com/on/. The arrow function would work, if you don't want `this` to refer to the select element inside the handler.

Comment: @t.niese so you mean , i can do another listener on container , then inside of it check for select change with `e.type==='select'`... please guide me

Comment: @Codenewbie `addEventListener` doesn't have the `selector` parameter, so jquery does something that vanilla js doesn't quite match. I only mentioned it because you seem to include jquery in the snippet

Comment: @ChrisLear thanks Chris , will sure check the API, but would nice if i could actually do it with JS ....

Comment: @Codenewbie you can add as many listeners as you want to one element, it won't replace the previously added ones.

Comment: got it @t.niese , thanks for the info :) ..... and if i had to target particular select with a class , i can add `target.type && target.type === 'select' && class here` ??

Comment: Basically yes but it would be `select-one` and not `select`, (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many listeners as you want to one element, it won't replace the previously added ones

So you can do it the same way as for your `click` event:

```
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type && tgt.type === "select-one" /* && some additional checks to identify the correct element, like class, name, … */) {
     // do something
  }
})
```

The `type` of a [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/type) is:

> `select-multiple` if multiple values can be selected.
> `select-one` if only one value can be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very basic implementation, using vanilla js.

```js
const resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
const getList = document.getElementById("example");

document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type && tgt.type === "radio") {
    const hide = tgt.classList.contains("verify-no");
    [...tgt.closest(".card-body").querySelectorAll("p.card-text")].forEach(par => par.classList.toggle("d-none", hide))
  }
})

getList.addEventListener("click", e => {

  let results = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  results.forEach((el, idx) => {
    //carousel
    const carouselItem = document.createElement("div");
    if (idx === 1) {
      carouselItem.classList.add("carousel-item", "active");
    }
    carouselItem.classList.add("carousel-item");

    //row below carousel
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add("row");

    //column for rows
    const column = document.createElement("div");
    column.classList.add("col-md-12", "mb-3");

    // card for each carousel inside column
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");

    // card body for card
    const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
    cardBody.classList.add("card-body", "text-center");

    // card text (upload info)
    const cardTextUploadedOn = document.createElement("p");
    cardTextUploadedOn.classList.add("card-text");
    cardTextUploadedOn.innerText = "adsadad";

    const cardTextUploadedBy = document.createElement("p");
    cardTextUploadedBy.classList.add("card-text");
    cardTextUploadedBy.innerText = "adsadad";

    // show predictions
    const formGroup = document.createElement("div");
    formGroup.classList.add("form-group", "row");

    const predLabel = document.createElement("div");
    predLabel.classList.add("col-lg-12");
    predLabel.innerText = "Select";

    const dummy = document.createElement("div");
    dummy.classList.add("col-sm-10");

    formGroup.appendChild(predLabel);
    formGroup.appendChild(dummy);

    // yes / no options
    const verifyRow = document.createElement("div");
    verifyRow.classList.add("row");

    const verifyLegend = document.createElement("legend");
    verifyLegend.classList.add("col-form-label", "col-lg-12", "pt-0");
    verifyLegend.innerText = "Is this correct ?";

    const verifyDummy = document.createElement("div");
    verifyDummy.classList.add("col-sm-10");

    const verifyYesFormCheck = document.createElement("div");
    verifyYesFormCheck.classList.add("form-check");

    const verifyNoFormCheck = document.createElement("div");
    verifyNoFormCheck.classList.add("form-check");

    const yesInput = document.createElement("input");
    yesInput.classList.add("form-check-input", "verify-yes");
    yesInput.type = "radio";
    yesInput.checked = true; // this will check it
    yesInput.name = "choosePred" + idx;
    yesInput.value = "Yes";

    const verifyYesLabel = document.createElement("label");
    verifyYesLabel.classList.add("form-check-label", "verify-yes");
    verifyYesLabel.innerText = "Yes";

    const verifyNoLabel = document.createElement("label");
    verifyNoLabel.classList.add("form-check-label", "verify-no");
    verifyNoLabel.innerText = "No";

    const noInput = document.createElement("input");
    noInput.classList.add("form-check-input", "verify-no");
    noInput.type = "radio";
    noInput.name = "choosePred" + idx;
    noInput.value = "No";

    // yes no options end

    // select //
    const selectForm = document.createElement("div");
    selectForm.classList.add("form-group", "selectGroup");

    const selectCLabel = document.createElement("label");
    selectCLabel.innerText = "Select C";

    const selectPLabel = document.createElement("label");
    selectPLabel.innerText = "Select P";

    //select for crop options
    const selectC = document.createElement("select");
    selectC.classList.add("form-control", "c-select");
    selectC.addEventListener("change", e => {
      alert('changedC'); //<= event listener
    });

    //select for pest options
    const selectP = document.createElement("select");
    selectP.classList.add("form-control", "p-select");
    selectP.addEventListener("change", e => {
      alert('changedP'); //<= event listener
    });

    const c_names = ['abc', 'abcd', 'gef']

    for (const c of c_names) {
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.innerText = c;
      if (c === "Select") {
        option.selected = true;
      }
      selectC.appendChild(option);
    }

    // select //
    resultsDiv.appendChild(carouselItem);
    carouselItem.appendChild(row);
    row.appendChild(column);
    column.appendChild(card);
    card.appendChild(cardBody);
    cardBody.appendChild(cardTextUploadedBy);
    cardBody.appendChild(cardTextUploadedOn);
    cardBody.appendChild(formGroup);
    cardBody.appendChild(verifyRow);
    verifyRow.appendChild(verifyLegend);
    verifyRow.appendChild(verifyDummy);
    verifyDummy.appendChild(verifyYesFormCheck);
    verifyDummy.appendChild(verifyNoFormCheck);
    verifyYesFormCheck.appendChild(yesInput);
    verifyYesFormCheck.appendChild(verifyYesLabel);
    verifyNoFormCheck.appendChild(noInput);
    verifyNoFormCheck.appendChild(verifyNoLabel);
    cardBody.appendChild(selectForm);
    selectForm.appendChild(selectCLabel);
    selectForm.appendChild(selectC);
    selectForm.appendChild(selectPLabel);
    selectForm.appendChild(selectP);

  });
  // if needed later
  // [...document.querySelectorAll(".verify-yes")].forEach(radio =>  radio.checked=true)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.4/cropper.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/advisory-new.css') }}" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="example">Show results</button>

  <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row m-auto">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h3 class="mb-3">Some heading</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
          <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11.793l-3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L13.293 8.5H1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8z" />
            </svg>
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15 8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H2.707l3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L2.707 8.5H14.5A.5.5 0 0 0 15 8z" />
            </svg>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 m-auto shadow-lg p-3">
          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" id="results"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The question is about event delegation and not about directly attaching the event listeners.

Comment: I read it as "I am stuck completely on how to listen to dynamically created Select -> on change listener", which didn't sound like it was purely about delegation. But if it is about delegation, your answer (or the jquery suggestion) is better.

Comment: absolutely @ChrisLear  , with the bare knowledge i have on delegation i have put it the way , but may i know if we can attach listeners like the way you did ?

Comment: @Codenewbie you can run my code, which has alerts that show on change